# Mnemonic for C# generic types

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance, mnemonics

I often forget if i have to use [in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx) or [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) when defining covarient and contravarient generic types. In java i have the mnemonic PECS (producer extends consumer super) to help me. Do you know a similar mnemonic for c#?

Comment: RELB - Read Eric Lippert's Blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/

Comment: I infrequently define genetics, except when attempting to create 12 foot lizardmen, everybody like's lizardmen.

Comment: @Jimmy Hoffa - yah but anything over 10 feet is just overkill.

Comment: @Joel Etherton: They're lizardmen, overkill is the point

Comment: Isn't it fairly easy to know when to use each, since `in` means the interface is taking something in, and `out` means it is giving something out? I can never remember which is which of co- and contra-variance, but the usage of `in` and `out` is never a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Didn't they do this for us when they called them 'in' and 'out' rather than covariant and contravariant?  Just think: am I pushing values 'in', or getting them 'out'? If unsure, try 'out' - it is far more common (and easier to understand).

Comment: Although this is true, it is not very catchy.

Answer (score 1):

`in` types are passed `in` to functions; `out` types are returned `out` from functions.

Comment: This is not what mR_fr0g has asked for. He wants a mnemonic for in and out when used as generic class variance type modifiers (which is a new funcionality of C# 4.0), not the common, old usage on method parameters.

Comment: rsenna: That's exactly what rsenna asked for. When creating a generic interface, types that are only passed in to functions can get the `in` label and types that are only returned from functions can get the `out` label. Types that are both passed in and returned (or used as `ref` or `out` parameters) are invariant and can't get either label.

Answer (score 0):

When I don't remember, I always refer to `IEnumerable<out T>` (which means of course I have to remember the signature of that interface...). You can only get instances of T "out" of an `IEnumerable<out T>`, so it is covariant. If you can only pass instances of T "in" to an interface (or delegate, which is more common), it's contravariant.